# A drupal 7 website hosted on apache-php7.4 server.Everything was working till yesterday.All of sudden,I'm getting white page and unable to debug it

Tags: php, drupal-7

A drupal 7 website hosted on apache-php7.4 server.Everything was working till yesterday.All of sudden,I'm getting white page and unable to debug it. Help is required to find out the cause of error.

I have downloaded the content of the website to my local machine and upgraded the drupal version. But nothing is going on my way. Please suggest some troubleshoot method.

Comment: Start by looking in the PHP error log file

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: yes ,No error found